# django and heroku: serving static files locally bot not on heroku

Tags: django, heroku

This is my static files configuration:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

my `DEBUG` is `True` and my `urls.py` don't mention static at all:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^chats/', include('chats.urls')),

]
```

so locally I can get my static files served perfectly:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/dummy.css

.test_div {
    background-color: red;
}


curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/base.css
.... an admin CSS file gets served here ....
```

however, when I deploy the same exact configuration on Heroku - I get 404 errors for admin files and for my custom static files:

```
curl https://pleshka-timer.herokuapp.com/static/admin/css/base.css
... a 404 message....
```

The heroku `collectstatic` command that it runs with every code deployment finishes without errors. If I explore the dyno with `heroku run bash` I see that my `staticfiles` directory is sitting there, waiting to be served.

What am I missing?

By the way, I can always do this

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^chats/', include('chats.urls')),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

as per Django docs, and this would work; but why the hell should I do this if Heroku does the `collectstatic` routine for me?